# Amazon DynamoDB with .Net Framework - ConditionalCheckFailedException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-dynamodb

I have a .Net Framework MVC app and I integrated DynamoDB.

When I enter on any page, until the page is fully loaded, I get many DynamoDB errors.

[image: Output errors]
[image: Fiddler errors]

Does anyone know what the issue can be?
I checked a lot (found out that is related to Http Modules) but can not find any reason.

I have AWSSDK.Core (3.3.106.7) and AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 (3.3.105.29) packages installed.

After some more investigation I find that the error is because some files are missing. Example:

> Locating source for 'D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.cs'.
> The file 'D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.cs' does not exist

But I don't even have a `D:\` partition. Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing some operation with a condition expression and that condition isn't fulfilled, that's why you're getting a `ConditionalCheckFailed` exception.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html):

> **ConditionalCheckFailedException**
>
> Message: *The conditional request failed.*
>
> You specified a condition that evaluated to false. For example, you
> might have tried to perform a conditional update on an item, but the
> actual value of the attribute did not match the expected value in the
> condition.
>
> **OK to retry?** No

This is all I can tell you based on the amount of details (or lack thereof) you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't have any conditions used. It's not something code related I think.

Comment: You could check the CloudTrail response to the 400series errors, otherwise I'm inclined to take the SDKs word that there is some kind of Conditional Check here that you're not aware of.

Comment: I investigated a little more and find some more details, but still no clue about this

Comment: Any chance you used the `DynamoDBVersion` attribute? Optimistic concurrency is one of the most common ways to get a conditional check error.